# How to generate a proper service using .env variable in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, service

I have two services MysqlSearchProvider and ElasticSearchProvider.
I would like to use an environment variable to easily change which service is currently used for the search engine.

I tried to achieve something similar using service factory.

```
parameters:
    search_provider: 'mysql'

services:
    App\Factory\SearchService:
        factory: [ 'App\Factory\SearchServiceFactory', 'createSearchService' ]
        arguments:
            - '%search_provider%'
```

Factory:

```
class SearchServiceFactory
{
    public static function createSearchService($arguments): SearchServiceInterface
    {
        return new SearchService();
    }
}
```

Service:

```
class MysqlSearchService implements SearchServiceInterface
{

    public function search(): string
    {
        return 'base search';
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/')]
    public function test(SearchServiceInterface $interface /*???*/): Response
    {
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

However, I do not know how I could, for example, inject the appropriate service generated by the factory by injecting SearchServiceInterface.

Answer (score 0):

Omg, sometimes I don't think.

```
services:
App\Factory\SearchServiceInterface: '@App\Factory\SearchService'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).